# Inverse of an Elementary Matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Assume we have a 3x3 matrix like:

```
A =  9 8 7
     6 5 4
     3 2 1
```

We are applying an Elementary matrix E to A:

```
E = 1 0 0
    0 1 0
    0 3 1
```

which gives A':

```
A' = 9  8  7
     6  5  4
     21 17 13
```

I need to find an E' that satisfies `(E')*(A') = (A)` .I tried below method but I'm not sure if it is correct or not:

```
E*A = A' => Let's multiply both side with inverse of E:
(E^-1)*E*A = (E^-1)*A' ; (E^-1)*E = I ; I*A = A;
A = (E^-1)*A'
```

E is type 3 elementary matrix. So inverse of E:

```
(E^-1) = 1 0 0
         0 1 0
         0 -3 1
```

which is equal to E'. My question is, is this method correct, especially multiplying both sides with inverse of E.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is valid but one can also say
$$E'A'=A$$
$$E'EA=A$$
$$E'E=I$$
$$E'=E^{-1}$$
$E'E=I$ because the identity matrix satisfies $IA=A$.

Comment: The third equation implies the fourth only if $E$ is invertible, otherwise it is only a pseudo-inverse. You should probably explain why this is the only solution.

Comment: @sehigle You don't even need this to be the only solution. The question states "find an $E'$ that satisfies $\dots$"

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks, your method seems more convenient actually. sehigle; In this question, we already know that E is an elementary matrix. So we don't need to show that E is invertible.

Comment: @PeterForeman Uniqueness is easy to show and I just wanted to comment on the equivalence of your statements.